# multiple forms in one view rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

am new to stack overflow..hoping support from all f u
i have employee form with personal details,contact details,salary details etc,arranged,but they are different controllers.i want to get all data in one form in employee view.employee contacts and other forms are not getting saved...help out...
`

```
    <%= form_for(@employee, :html => {class: 'form-horizontal add_allignment employee_form', role: 'form'}) do |f| %>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <%= f.label :first_name, class: 'col-sm-3 form-control-label' %>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: 'form-control' %>
          <span class="error-block"><%= validation_error(@employee, :first_name) %></span>
        </div>
      </div>




      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-10">
          <%= f.button "Submit", type: 'button', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg', onclick: 'submit_my_form(this)' %>
        </div>
      </div>


  <% end %>

  </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane in" id="nav-tabs-0-2">
    <%= form_for(@employee.contact_components, :html => {class: 'form-horizontal add_allignment employee_form', role: 'form'}) do |e| %>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <%= e.label "P O Box", class: 'col-sm-3 form-control-label' %>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <%= e.text_field :po_box, class: 'form-control' %>
        <span class="error-block"><%= validation_error(@employee, :po_box) %></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <%= e.label :permanent_address, class: 'col-sm-3 form-control-label' %>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <%= e.text_area :permanent_address, class: 'form-control' %>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-10">
          <%= e.button "Submit", type: 'button', class: 'btn btn-primary btn-lg', onclick: 'submit_my_form(this)' %>
        </div>
      </div>

   <% end %>
  </div>

</div>`
```

Comment: Thanku soo much it helped me lot...

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a [nested form](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#building-complex-forms). It allows you to update different model attributes from a single form. That doc link will walk you through each change you need to make to the model, controller and views.